# Google App Engine - Need to clear GAE process written in PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

### I have two questions to clarify

I am new to google app engine. Need support clear some process of doing: 
 1. First Question:
I have create a simple app to test tutorials provided by the google. I need to clarify the way I did was correct.

Following is the way I implement:
app.yaml:

```
application: praveenhellogapp
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets


- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /googletutorials/
  script: googletutorials/linkstaticfile.php

- url: .*
  script: linkstopages.php
```

you can check the output I deploy to the [GAE cloud](http://praveenhellogapp.appspot.com/): 
http://praveenhellogapp.appspot.com/

2. Second Question

I do not understand the script: \1 concept clear. what is the use of doing script: \1 
"url: /(.+.php)$
  script: \1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the handlers matters, so your 3rd rule, i.e. /(.+.php)$ takes precedence over the 4th and 5th. As for the regex syntax, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression for more details. The \1 represents whatever is matched in the URL. In other words, a request to /foo.php will invoke the script foo.php in your app folder.

Comment: for the current order it works fine for me. should it be as the last every time?? also if I use \2 or different number there will not be any changes...

Comment: For most PHP apps not using apache rewrite, this is likely to be the last rule. Since there's only one matched subexpression in the rule, \2 wouldn't make any sense.